# Pymupdf highlight difference between 2 pdf pages

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

Trying to compare 2 `pdf pages - p1 and p2` and highlight the difference in `p1`

Algorithm:

```
1. Get text_blocks with bounding_box from each_page
2. Compare text_blocks of p1 with p2
3. for every text_block which is different use the respective bounding_box to highlight the diffeerence
```

Code:

```
def get_text_blocks(page):

    blocks = []
    blocks_bbox = []
    blocks = page.get_text_blocks()
    for block in blocks:
        #appending the bounding box of the block
        blocks_bbox.append(block[0:4])
        #appending the text from the block
        blocks.append(block[4])
   return blocks, blocks_bbox
```

difference psuedo_code:

```
diff = [list of text_blocks IN p1 and NOT IN p2]
for each_diff in diff:  
     #get the bounding_box of the difference block
     rect = fitz.rect(bounding_box)
     annot = p1.add_highlight_annot(rect)
     annot.update()
```

This works. But in certain cases though the `contents` are `identical` they get grouped into `different text blocks` so while comparing it is highlighting wrong.

Example:

p1:

```
block_1: line1, line2
block_2: line3
```

p2:

```
block_1: line1, line2, line3
```

Though the identical 3 lines (back-to-back) - `line1, line2, line3` are present in both the pages `p1` and `p2` since the `blocks` are different it is getting flagged

Also, tried the `get_text` and compare `line by line` approach, it is not working.

Any suggestions on how to fix this will be helpful?

Comment: See my suggestion on our home page on GitHub.